# Wordpress multisite by path with multiple domains

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I'm currently hosting an internal wordpress multisite installation at `wordpress.local` and all my sites are on different paths (e.g. `wordpress.local/site1`).

I am trying to use a proxy to expose this to the internet now on `example.com`, however all links and sources are using `wordpress.local`. I've tried to rewrite the response by finding and replacing `wordpress.local` with `example.local` but this is missing some sources such as those that are url encoded.

I've tried to bodge multisite into coping with this with the following config:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$protocol = ((isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']===443) || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'])==="https")) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $host);
define('WP_SITEURL', $protocol . $host . '/wp');
define('WP_HOME', $protocol . $host);
```

But obviously this is throwing an error now saying that it cannot find site `example.com`. Is there anyway to configure wordpress to use relative urls for everything or setup multisite to ignore the host give that I am not using the subdomain installation?